# Is it possible to show these parsed results faster, by using oop?

Tags: php

Hi everyone so my code below works just fine... i am crawling something and then putting it in the properties of the class but i think that i `dry` `Don’t Repeat Yourself` a lot in this one... and i am asking if anyone can say a better way to show these results with less code.

```
$card0 = new Main($titleNamesArr[0],$imageArr[0],$pathArr[0],$subtitleArr[0],$subtitleArr[1],$descriptionArr[0],$detailsArr[0]);
   echo $card0->__toString()."<br>"."<br>";

$card1 = new Main($titleNamesArr[1],$imageArr[1],$pathArr[1],$subtitleArr[2],$subtitleArr[3],$descriptionArr[1],$detailsArr[1]);
    echo $card1->__toString()."<br>"."<br>";

$card2 = new Main($titleNamesArr[2],$imageArr[2],$pathArr[2],$subtitleArr[4],$subtitleArr[5],$descriptionArr[2],$detailsArr[2]);
    echo $card2->__toString()."<br>"."<br>";

$card3 = new Main($titleNamesArr[3],$imageArr[3],$pathArr[3],$subtitleArr[6],$subtitleArr[7],$descriptionArr[3],$detailsArr[3]);
    echo $card3->__toString()."<br>"."<br>";

$card4 = new Main($titleNamesArr[4],$imageArr[4],$pathArr[4],$subtitleArr[8],$subtitleArr[9],$descriptionArr[4],$detailsArr[4]);
    echo $card4->__toString()."<br>"."<br>";

$card5 = new Main($titleNamesArr[5],$imageArr[5],$pathArr[5],$subtitleArr[10],$subtitleArr[11],$descriptionArr[5],$detailsArr[5]);
    echo $card5->__toString()."<br>"."<br>";

$card6 = new Main($titleNamesArr[6],$imageArr[6],$pathArr[6],$subtitleArr[12],$subtitleArr[13],$descriptionArr[6],$detailsArr[6]);
    echo $card6->__toString()."<br>"."<br>";

$card7 = new Main($titleNamesArr[7],$imageArr[7],$pathArr[7],$subtitleArr[14],$subtitleArr[15],$descriptionArr[7],$detailsArr[7]);
    echo $card7->__toString()."<br>"."<br>";

$card8 = new Main($titleNamesArr[8],$imageArr[8],$pathArr[8],$subtitleArr[16],$subtitleArr[17],$descriptionArr[8],$detailsArr[8]);
    echo $card8->__toString()."<br>"."<br>";

$card9 = new Main($titleNamesArr[9],$imageArr[9],$pathArr[9],$subtitleArr[18],$subtitleArr[19],$descriptionArr[9],$detailsArr[9]);
    echo $card9->__toString()."<br>"."<br>";

$card10 = new Main($titleNamesArr[10],$imageArr[10],$pathArr[10],$subtitleArr[20],$subtitleArr[21],$descriptionArr[10],$detailsArr[10]);
    echo $card9->__toString()."<br>"."<br>";

$card11 = new Main($titleNamesArr[11],$imageArr[11],$pathArr[11],$subtitleArr[22],$subtitleArr[23],$descriptionArr[11],$detailsArr[11]);
    echo $card11->__toString()."<br>"."<br>";

$card12 = new Main($titleNamesArr[12],$imageArr[12],$pathArr[12],$subtitleArr[24],$subtitleArr[25],$descriptionArr[12],$detailsArr[12]);
    echo $card12->__toString()."<br>"."<br>";

$card13 = new Main($titleNamesArr[13],$imageArr[13],$pathArr[13],$subtitleArr[26],$subtitleArr[27],$descriptionArr[13],$detailsArr[13]);
    echo $card13->__toString()."<br>"."<br>";
```

Comment: The only OOP you need is the one in L**OOP**S

Comment: I am on my way to go search, thank you for time sir

Comment: Here you go: https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php